# What's the terminology for a subgroup that is not a normal subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, terminology, normal-subgroups

On [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_subgroup) of normal subgroup, there are a few candidates, but it seems they all refer to something more specific:

- Subgroup properties complementary (or opposite) to normality

  - Malnormal subgroup
  - Contranormal subgroup
  - Abnormal subgroup
  - Self-normalizing subgroup

The abnormal subgroup is most close to what I want, i.e.,

> all subgroups = normal ones + not-normal ones

but it also includes the whole group.

Comment: Perhaps you can use the term "proper abnormal subgroups"?

Comment: Why not simply non-normal subgroup?

Comment: Or what @HagenvonEitzen which would have been my first choice.

Comment: Not all non-normal subgroups are abnormal.

Comment: it is **not** true that a subgroup that is not normal must be malnormal, contranormal, abnormal, or self-normalizing. Those are properties related to normality/behavior under conjugation, but not the negation of normality.

Comment: non-normal sounds good to me. I wasn't sure if some convention exists already